# Remove query string from URL as part of a PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string

I've created a button on my `Wordpress` site which allows my users to change their location from `'London'` to `'Manchester'`.

The button uses `$_POST` to start a PHP function.

As part of that `PHP` function I want to `'clean'` the `URL` of the page the user is on (i.e. remove the query strings) because if there are any query strings when they change locations it can mess things up when they try and use filters.

I've found a way to get a clean URL

```
$url=strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');
```

And I thought I might be able to use

```
wp_redirect($url);
```

To refresh the page with a clean `URL` - but doesn't seem to work.

I think the reason this question is unique is it is related to a function that is started by a $_POST request, rather than hooked to an action which is being loaded. As a result, the page isn't fully reloaded. I have looked at other questions which tell me how to remove the query string (which is helpful enough) but not redirect me at the end.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing query string in PHP (sometimes based on referrer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270677/removing-query-string-in-php-sometimes-based-on-referrer)

Comment: Thanks Andy. I had seen that and explained why I think my situation is different / why those don't work.

Comment: can you please show your code here ?

Comment: So this really doesn't relate to removing the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Javascript to refresh the page, with a function that removed the query string:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location = window.location.pathname; }, 150)">
    <input type="submit" name="switchman" id="switchman" value="Switch to Manchester" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
header("Location: ".$url);
```

Comment: Here are a few types of PHP redirects you can try (some you may need AJAX to use). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
$url = strtok((empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http://' : 'https://').$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');
```